# How to upload file to AWS S3 using AWS AppSync

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-appsync

Following [this docs/tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/building-a-client-app-react.html#complex-objects) in AWS AppSync Docs.

It states:

> With AWS AppSync you can model these as GraphQL types. If any of your mutations have a variable with bucket, key, region, mimeType and localUri fields, the SDK will upload the file to Amazon S3 for you.

However, I cannot make my file to upload to my s3 bucket. I understand that tutorial missing a lot of details. More specifically, the tutorial does not say that the `NewPostMutation.js` needs to be changed.

I changed it the following way:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export default gql`
mutation AddPostMutation($author: String!, $title: String!, $url: String!, $content: String!, $file: S3ObjectInput ) {
    addPost(
        author: $author
        title: $title
        url: $url
        content: $content
        file: $file
    ){
        __typename
        id
        author
        title
        url
        content
        version
    }
}
`
```

Yet, even after I have implemented these changes, the file did not get uploaded...

Comment: Do you have AWS credentials for the S3 bucket? What is the AppSync authorization scheme you're using?

Comment: I tried to use different schemes. Which one should I use?

Comment: You'll need AWS IAM credentials, I suggest using Cognito Identity for this. If you're looking to do this easily in an app check out AWS Amplify: https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify

Comment: Thank you @Richard! I will revisit this tutorial. I wish someone from the aws amazon checked those tutorials before posting them online. I had to make lots of adjustments to make the aforementioned tutorial work.

Comment: can you tell us what adjustments? or perhaps post your working code?

Comment: Hi @MichaelEconomy. Sorry for not being clear. In the context of the conversation, I meant that I made the tutorial work, till the moment with the S3 bucket upload. Please let me know if you need help with any preceding sections.

Comment: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-amplify-graphql/blob/master/photo-client/src/Components/AddPhoto.js .   try this example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload an image to AWS S3 using GraphQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45625548/how-to-upload-an-image-to-aws-s3-using-graphql)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There's a few moving parts under the hood you need to make sure you have in place before this "just works" (TM).  First of all, you need to make sure you have an appropriate input and type for an S3 object defined in your GraphQL schema

```
enum Visibility {
    public
    private
}

input S3ObjectInput {
    bucket: String!
    region: String!
    localUri: String
    visibility: Visibility
    key: String
    mimeType: String
}

type S3Object {
    bucket: String!
    region: String!
    key: String!
}
```

The `S3ObjectInput` type, of course, is for use when uploading a new file - either by way of creating or updating a model within which said S3 object metadata is embedded.  It can be handled in the request resolver of a mutation via the following:

```
{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "operation": "PutItem",
    "key": {
        "id": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.input.id),
    },

    #set( $attribs = $util.dynamodb.toMapValues($ctx.args.input) )
    #set( $file = $ctx.args.input.file )
    #set( $attribs.file = $util.dynamodb.toS3Object($file.key, $file.bucket, $file.region, $file.version) )

    "attributeValues": $util.toJson($attribs)
}
```

This is making the assumption that the S3 file object is a child field of a model attached to a DynamoDB datasource.  Note that the call to `$utils.dynamodb.toS3Object()` sets up the complex S3 object `file`, which is a field of the model with a type of `S3ObjectInput`.  Setting up the request resolver in this way handles the upload of a file to S3 (when all the credentials are set up correctly - we'll touch on that in a moment), but it doesn't address how to get the `S3Object` back.  This is where a field level resolver attached to a local datasource becomes necessary.  In essence, you need to create a local datasource in AppSync and connect it to the model's `file` field in the schema with the following request and response resolvers:

```
## Request Resolver ##
{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "payload": {}
}

## Response Resolver ##
$util.toJson($util.dynamodb.fromS3ObjectJson($context.source.file))
```

This resolver simply tells AppSync that we want to take the JSON string that is stored in DynamoDB for the `file` field of the model and parse it into an `S3Object` - this way, when you do a query of the model, instead of returning the string stored in the `file` field, you get an object containing the `bucket`, `region`, and `key` properties that you can use to build a URL to access the S3 Object (either directly via S3 or using a CDN - that's really dependent on your configuration).

Do make sure you have credentials set up for complex objects, however (told you I'd get back to this).  I'll use a React example to illustrate this - when defining your AppSync parameters (endpoint, auth, etc.), there is an additional property called `complexObjectCredentials` that needs to be defined to tell the client what AWS credentials to use to handle S3 uploads, e.g.:

```
const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
    url: AppSync.graphqlEndpoint,
    region: AppSync.region,
    auth: {
        type: AUTH_TYPE.AWS_IAM,
        credentials: () => Auth.currentCredentials()
    },
    complexObjectsCredentials: () => Auth.currentCredentials(),
});
```

Assuming all of these things are in place, S3 uploads and downloads via AppSync should work.

Comment: I am using react-native instead of reactJS. How do I load image complex object from react native to AppSync when I am using things like imagepicker? the example here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/building-a-client-app-react.html only provides example with <Input/> but doesn't have example using imagepickers. I have tried providing just the local uri but that does not work - document is created; however, s3 object is not uploaded.

Comment: I haven't researched whether this would work, but couldn't you use a hidden <Input/> with an imagepicker and have the imagepicker call a method that updates the hidden <Input/> with the appropriate file object?

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the discussion.  For mobile clients, amplify (or if doing from aws console) will encapsulate mutation calls into an object.  The clients won't auto upload if the encapsulation exists.  So you can modify the mutation call directly in aws console so that the upload *file : S3ObjectInput* is in the calling parameters.  This was happening the last time I tested (Dec 2018) following the docs.

You would change to this calling structure:

```
 type Mutation {
        createRoom(
        id: ID!,
        name: String!,
        file: S3ObjectInput,
        roomTourId: ID
    ): Room
}
```

Instead of autogenerated calls like:

```
type Mutation {
    createRoom(input: CreateRoomInput!): Room
}
input CreateRoomInput {
    id: ID
    name: String!
    file: S3ObjectInput
}
```

Once you make this change both iOS and Android will happily upload your content if you do what @hatboyzero has outlined.

[Edit] I did a bit of research, supposedly this has been fixed in 2.7.3 https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-android/issues/11.  They likely addressed iOS but I didn't check.