# Handling 'heavy' data in GraphQL mutation

Tags: javascript, graphql

Is there a nice way of dealing with 'heavy' payload when designing a mutation?

I'm talking about the cases where the goal is, for instance, to upload a large file, like 50MB or more. The idea of getting base64 string does not seem appealing to me (although it perfectly works with small-sized files) as I don't have any data about how the graphql will behave if it gets a huge amount of data

I did some research and found [one thing](https://github.com/jaydenseric/apollo-upload-server) that can do this, however, I'd like to create an alternative option because:

1. It was created to be used with Apollo
2. This package uses [mjs](https://github.com/cesanta/mjs) (which I've never worked with and therefore, I have some troubles reading the source code)

So, is there a way to somehow pass large amount of data to the graphql mutation?

Comment: How about relating your schema to S3? Like mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48495338/4636715